# Creating a new scheduled task with Powershell v2 from XML

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I need to use Powershell v2 to create a new scheduled task. what I tried so far is the task scheduler com object as follows:

```
$task_path = "c:\Temp\tasks\*.xml"
$task_user = "Administrator"
$task_pass = "mypass"

$sch = New-Object -ComObject("Schedule.Service")
$sch.connect("localhost")
$folder = $sch.GetFolder("\")

Get-Item $task_path | %{
    $task_name = $_.Name.Replace('.xml', '')
    $task_xml = Get-Content $_.FullName

    $task = $sch.NewTask($null)

    $task.XmlText = $task_xml

    $folder.RegisterTaskDefinition($task_name, $task, 6, $task_user, $task_pass, 1, $null)
}
```

Now the problem i'm facing with this is that i don't want to specify any additional info in the method `RegisterTaskDefinition` other than the task name and the task object, because everything is in the XML file, even the username and password.

How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
schtasks.exe /Create /XML C:\task.xml /tn taskname
```

Hope it helps!